# Access Browser History with CSS

Tags: css

I have to do some research for University, sadly I don't find anything on the internet for this specific topic.
The Assignment is

`"How and under which circumstances is it possible to discover some visited pages with a CSS-Trick? How does it work? Do you think it's possible to design the technology behind it different?"`

I have never heard about CSS being able to access browser history. Does anyone have any articles or blogposts or whatever about this topic?

Comment: They probably refer to the :visited pseudo-class https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Comment: This looks like what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned in the comments by arieljuod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66734391/access-browser-history-with-css#comment117965991_66734391), your assignment is referring to the `:visited` pseudo-class, which you can find more info about in [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited):

> The `:visited` CSS pseudo-class represents links that the user has already visited. For privacy reasons, the styles that can be modified using this selector are very limited.

That MDN page has a whole section on the privacy-related parts of the usage restrictions of the pseudo-class, and links to another page completely dedicated to discussion of privacy aspects and what certain browsers (firefox). A brief quote is inserted below:

> Before about 2010, the CSS `:visited` selector allowed websites to uncover a user's browsing history and figure out what sites the user had visited. This was done through [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and other techniques. This process was quick to execute, and made it possible not only to determine where the user had been on the web, but could also be used to guess a lot of information about the user's identity.
>
> To mitigate this problem, browsers have limited the amount of information that can be obtained from visited links.